# Call struct overrload output inside class overrload output

Tags: c++11

This is my code:

```
 struct Term{

   int coeff;
   int expo;
   Term* next;
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Term& rt);
 };

class Polynomial{

  public:
    Term *head;
    Polynomial();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Polynomial& a_poly);
};
```

How  can I use  use the operator<< function defined for the Term 
struct inside operator << function defined for Polynomial Class ?

Comment: Maybe something like `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Polynomial& a_poly) { os << *(a_poly.head); return os; }` ?

Comment: @max66 there are two operator theire.
this one 
`ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Polynomial& a_poly){
os << a_poly.head;
}`
shoudl call this one 
`ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Term& rt){
  os << rt.coeff << "x^" << rt.expo;
}`

Comment: yes: the instruction `os << a_poly.head;` (better: `os << *(a_poly.head);`, because `head` is a pointer to `Term` and the other operator is defined over `Term`, not over `Term *`) should call the other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of creating `operator<<(ostream& os, ...)` for types is to hide print implementation details for caller, so one can simply put an object into a stream. Thus, call as if it was `int` or `std::string`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Polynomial& a_poly)
{
    // dereference the pointer and compiler will choose Term's operator<< 
    os << *(a_poly.head);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: that is not working at all.
I dont want to access any value of struct as you did a_poly.head
i want to do this: 

there are two operator theire. this one 
`ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Polynomial& a_poly){ os << a_poly.head; }`
shoudl call this one 
`ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Term& rt){ os << rt.coeff << "x^" << rt.expo; }`